# Stack traces don't show in Rails Console after Ruby version upgrade

Tags: exception, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running Rails 5.1.7 and was using Ruby 2.4.3. I don't have the option to upgrade my Rails version presently, and due to Rails 5.1.x compatibility, I'm forced to go onto Ruby 2.5.x at max.

Due to a Ruby bug causing segfaults in 2.4.3, I have to upgrade Ruby to a different version.

Ruby 2.5.8 has an issue that stack traces no longer appear in Rails Console or when running Puma in development for me. Stack traces do appear when running `irb`, just not `rails c`.

I've confirmed that changing back to Ruby 2.4.3 with no other changes to the code or gems fixes the issue and stack traces appear again.

Any ideas as to how I can get stack traces in the later Ruby version?

**Ruby 2.4.3 - Rails Console**

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.7)
2.4.3 :001 > raise 'test'
RuntimeError: test
        from (irb):1
2.4.3 :002 >
```

**Ruby 2.5.8 - Rails Console**

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.7)
2.5.8 :001 > raise 'test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
RuntimeError (test)
2.5.8 :002 >
```

This is just the minimum steps required for reproduction, the same issue occurs when an exception is thrown in the code.

For comparison, this is what shows up for `irb`

**Ruby 2.4.3 - irb**

```
$ irb
2.4.3 :001 > raise 'test'
RuntimeError: test
        from (irb):1
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.4.3 :002 >
```

**Ruby 2.5.8 - irb**

```
$ irb
2.5.8 :001 > raise 'test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):1
RuntimeError (test)
2.5.8 :002 >
```

Answer (score 0):

This was due to gems I had in my bundle that were meant for giving a pretty exception output in development.

```
gem 'better_errors'
gem 'binding_of_caller'
```

Once those were updated to newer versions, stack traces were once again available in the `rails console`.

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.7)
2.5.8 :001 > raise 'test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
RuntimeError (test)
2.5.8 :002 >
```